# How do I bring a page template into a new theme with separate styling?

Tags: themes, templates, child-theme

I currently have a page template that I have striped of all major styling within a theme (twentyninteen-child).

I have a new child theme (event), that this page/template will sit under and am having trouble incorporating it. There are so many posts that say different things, I am getting confused and have crashed my UAT multiple times.

The page will sit separate from the site and will not (at this time) have a header or footer of the larger site that it will sit in. Below is the code that partially works.

```
<?php /* Template Name: My template */ ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
    <?php function mypage_head() {
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="'.get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory').'/css/style.css">'."\n";
}
add_action('wp_head', 'mypage_head');
?>
</head>
<body class="page-template-connect-home-placeholder">
```

Is this what I should be doing if I want a page template to have completely different styling to the rest of the site?

EDITED:
After trying quite a few things I have just referenced the other themes styling in the template. It's probably not the best way of doing it, but it works. I used the `<link rel="stylesheet" href="">` and removed the `<?php wp_head(); ?>` tag. I need to update the style in the other section as it was thrown out a bit, but can use the other theme fine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your theme still load the main style.css sheet, because it is called by `wp_head()`. See [the documentation here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.2/src/wp-includes/default-filters.php#L282)

So, in order to not load your theme main stylesheet, you have to add to your `functions.php` file :

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'yolo_my_custom_template' );
function yolo_my_custom_template(){
    if ( is_page_template( 'name_of_your_page_template.php' ) ) :
      wp_deregister_script('twentynineteen-style');
      wp_deregister_script('twentynineteen-print-style');
    endif;
}
```

Comment: I added it into my new themes child and it didn't do anything.

Comment: Hi, did you change `name_of_your_page_template.php` by the real name of your "My template" template file ?

Comment: Yes, I ended up just referencing the styles. As this is a completely separate template. Thanks for your help.